# Clicking a button to open new activity showing data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to coding so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I have managed to set up a button which opens a new activity in my Kotlin android project. I want to be able to display the data from my firebase batabase in the new activity when the button is clicked but have no idea how to go about it.

For example, I have 3 buttons for 3 places. Each button opens the same activity which should display the data corresponding to that place in certain textviews (name, addess, etc)

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of individual steps in here, that you should be able to find existing sources for. For example, do you know [how to open an activity](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+an+activity+in+kotlin) and [how to pass information to an activity](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+informarion+to+an+activity)? And do you know, [how to read data from Firebase](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+data+from+firebase+realtime+database+in+kotlin)?

Comment: I have managed to open an activty. For passing information and reading data I have done a ittle reading but not sure whuch activity and where I should be putting the code. Im assuming I put the pass info code into my button codes on my main activity page. But for the read data code I'm not sure where i shoudl be putting that.

Comment: @Matt canyou share your you have done?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect. Please also respond using @AlexMamo